# Nothing returned after authentication?

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, web-services, authentication

When I try to return the student using this method it doesn't show anything or any error, if I however don't put anything in the password box I get a 404 error so I know its working so my authenticate method isn't working, I basically want to authenticate the user and return something from the student collection, like the FirstName?

```
private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uri = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AuthenticateStudent/{0}/{1}", textBox28.Text, textBox29.Text);
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
    var Tag12 = xDoc.Descendants("Student")
        .Select(n => new
        {
            FirstName = n.Element("FirstName").Value,
        })
        .ToList();


    dataGridView12.DataSource = Tag12;
}
```

Comment: Did you add a web reference to the WCf in the client??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a special return type that includes the boolean you're currently returning, as well as the Student:

```
public class AuthenticationResult
{
    public bool IsValid {get;set;}
    public Student ValidatedStudent {get;set;}
}
```

Then return an object of this type from your WCF method:

```
public AuthenticationResult AuthenticateStudent(string studentID, string password)
{
    var result = students.FirstOrDefault(n => n.StudentID == studentID);
    bool flag = false;
    if (result != null) {...}

    ...
    return new AuthenticationResult {IsValid = flag, ValidatedStudent = result};
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks, so what about my actual authentication method I am still stuck with the  `flag = UserPassword.ToList().SequenceEqual(StudentFound.Salt);` it should be studentfound.Password from my datacontract Student but if I set it to that I get an error on the entire line saying you cant convert list to `iqueryable<char>`

Comment: @KirstyWhite: You've asked multiple questions with this post. Try narrowing down the issue with the password check and ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Ok Stripling I will try, just hard to explain